# Is there any difference between AD620 vs INA128?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier, biopotential, eeg

I'm trying to make an EMG sensor.

I've found some tutorials, for example, [DIY muscle sensor/EMG circuit for a microcontroller](https://www.instructables.com/id/Muscle-EMG-Sensor-for-a-Microcontroller/), but my main question is can I make an EMG sensor using AD620 instead of INA128? Because I can't find INA128 in my city.

Comment: Without a target circuit to compare potential replacement of the original with the latter device, this question is indeed silly.

Comment: EMG amp defines a exact range of solutions > Andy

Comment: [These folks built an EMG amplifier.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261265857_Optimized_circuit_for_EMG_signal_processing)  They simulated a circuit with the AD620 - the circuits are all in the paper.  So, yes, you can do it.  Whether it will work as well as the INA128 is another question.

Comment: And, yes, there are lots of differences between the INA128 and the AD620.  Which ones matter depends on the actual circuit used.  At a quick glance, they seem to have the same pin connections.  If you plug in one instead of the other, then it won't go boom.  Might not do much useful, though.

Answer (score 1):

The AD620 is also an equivalent INA thanks to @ Scott and @JRE

Gain is set with one external resistor (Gain range 1 to 10,000).   The INA138 is 1 + (50 kΩ/RG)
**Can you read the datasheet for AD620 to find any difference?**

> Low Cost Low Power Instrumentation Amplifier.
>
> Wide power supply range (±2.3 V to ±18 V)
>   Higher performance than 3 op amp IA designs
>   Available in 8-lead DIP and SOIC packaging 
>   Low power, 1.3 mA max supply current
>
> Excellent dc performance (B grade)
>   50 μV max, input offset voltage
>   0.6 μV/°C max, input offset drift
>   1.0 nA max, input bias current
>   100 dB min common-mode rejection ratio (G = 10).
>   Low noise
>   9 nV/√Hz @ 1 kHz, input voltage noise 0.28 μV p-p noise (0.1 Hz to 10 Hz)
>   Excellent ac specifications
>   120 kHz bandwidth (G = 100) 15 μs settling time to 0.01%

Make sure your  cables must be balanced to get adequate or same CMRR with STP cables or similar.

You can easily find these designs and examples in Google images.  Let’s see you try and update your question with a schematic.

Unless you at using batteries or know what you are doing with SMPS, we are cautious about mixing earth grounds.
[the reason why medical PS have low leakage](https://neupsykey.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/B9781455726721000404_f040-005-9781455726721.jpg)

Since EMG and EKG amps expect x mV signals as opposed to head skin signals (alpha, Beta waves etc.) which are in the xx uV range, it is pretty easy to make it work without  hum with a good linear supply or battery operated.  SMPS often add high CM noise that can be shunted to earth ground with 1nF max between floating 0V and E-gnd.

Also read all the wiki on EMG and this about placement of sensors.  https://www.delsys.com/Attachments_pdf/TN101%20-%20EMG%20Sensor%20Placement-web.pdf

Also “skin galvanic response” which a transient from sensor interface motion.

Then add a precision OA Peak detector and buffer to get the envelope DC output to drive lights and motors in a feedback loop for giggles with pressure sensors.

For more fun, put a sticky electrode on each temple and move eyes side to side to generate a triangle wave.

Comment: Who is your target audience? Is OP in that audience?

Comment: Of course Harry.  https://www.google.ca/search?q=emg+ina&client=safari&hl=en-ca&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA_PuYi__dAhUI44MKHXlbBzgQ_AUIESgB&biw=694&bih=666

Comment: This covers the whole range of DIY EMG

Comment: The AD620 has 100dB CMR. So, it starts off better than the three opamp solution.  The AD620 **is** an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: Actually, the AD620  is an instrumentation amp, with an internal 3 op amp structure.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSeidman for the correction. In which equivalent with minor differences

Comment: Mywifisignal is weak on the beach in Baja Cali sorry for my mistral;)

Comment: I'd really suggest only battery operation, at least for the INA (and uC if any). The rest of the circuit (after digitization and serial output from uC) can be run on an SMPS (mains power) but ONLY AFTER PROPER OPTOCOUPLER ISOLATION. [My comment has nothing to do with the question, but the newbie like question and the answer involving smps prompts me to put this warning/reminder in here.]

Comment: @Indraneel What is the worst case current with 1nF based on leakage to shunt ratio that you might expect?  I realize medical PS have much lower leakage, while 250uA is std safe level for consumer grade.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I don't know. But it's not the leakage, it's the component failure. For a medical device, it means instant painful death. Typically, the INA and associated uC is run from an 1:1 isolation transformer. This is a small toroid with wire turns separated by a 1 cm gap between them. One side is run via an smps that produces 5V RMS and the other side also produces the same but is not checked. This unchecked side is then smoothed to DC and regulated with a linear regulator. But for a hobbyist, using a battery is much simpler.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist All that is for an ECG/EMG/EEG which does not have direct heart contact. For things like dialysis machines, the requirements are much more strict.

Comment: The method I suggested shunts stray leakage of say 50pf coupling to gnd with 1000pF so impedance divider plus the resistance from supply to inputs is pretty high thus the impulse attenuation is a lot more than 200:1. But due to unknown multiple medical equipment ground sources, for many instruments, the standards are strict.  But this this DIY user, not so.

Comment: The standards regarding stray leakage are actually to save the people other than the patient. A hospital is messy, there are liquids everywhere, the floor and clothes may be wet etc. For the patient, the signal already runs through a 1 meg or 10 meg resistor to a high input impedance INA. Theoretically, nothing should happen even if the power supply for the INA runs off mains. But, obviously, no one wants to do that.

Comment: But for a newbie DIY project, it’s not so messy. 1M is used to bleed off slowly say 10kV of ESD for shoes straps or wrist strap working on a bench. While walking across a nylon carpet with neoprene soled shoes generating a nice arc with a key to a door knob.  So what are you worried about for this DIY user?  What is your analysis? I did mine.  This is not debate on why medical stds exist for any hospital, but for home or lab experiments.